# Where is the Android Editor in the main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I cant find the Editor which would allow me to drag and drop controls into the graphical interface in the main xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  should try changing the android version which is at  right side set it to its respective 
  version  like  whatever you have set ,you  might have change it by mistake,try changing it   and you will get the view,    if its work let me know  , 
  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you open the xml in Eclipse (with android SDK installed) you should see two labels below the opened file. "Graphical Layout" and "main.xml". Click on "**Graphical Layout**".

Answer (score 1):

The graphical interface builder in eclipse is fairly rubbish. It should be visible via a tab at the bottom of the code editor window when you open your xml file ie (main.xml). You should see two tabs "Graphical Layout" and  ie "main.xml".

There is a better GUI builder called DroidDraw at http://www.droiddraw.org/. You can install it locally or build via the web browser. You can build your interface then copy and paste the XML result into the eclipse xml file.

Both GUi builders are basic though and i simply learn to write the XML by hand. The eclipse gui builder always bugs out for me and 9/10 of my XMl files won't even render in it so i ignore it completely...

Hope that helps